# Transforming a Spring Webflux Mono to an Either, preferably without blocking?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, arrow-kt

I'm using Kotlin and [Arrow](http://arrow-kt.io/) and the [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client) from `spring-webflux`. What I'd like to do is to transform a [Mono](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) instance to an [Either](https://arrow-kt.io/learn/typed-errors/either-and-ior/).

The `Either` instance is created by calling `Either.right(..)` when the response of the `WebClient` is successful or `Either.left(..)` when `WebClient` returns an error.

What I'm looking for is a method in `Mono` similar to [Either.fold(..)](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/ee18d155ca24f378224520f8131db7ef72bb587c/modules/core/arrow-core/src/main/kotlin/arrow/core/Either.kt#L52) where I can map over the successful and erroneous result and return a different type than a `Mono`. Something like this (pseudo-code which doesn't work):

```
val either : Either<Throwable, ClientResponse> = 
                   webClient().post().exchange()
                                .fold({ throwable -> Either.left(throwable) },
                                      { response -> Either.right(response)})
```

How should one go about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `fold` method on `Mono` but you can achieve the same using two methods: `map` and `onErrorResume`. It would go something like this:

```
val either : Either<Throwable, ClientResponse> = 
               webClient().post()
                          .exchange()
                          .map { Either.right(it) }
                          .onErrorResume { Either.left(it).toMono() }
```